# How to rename a file multiple times (Python)

Tags: python

My dilemma is that I want to non destructively go about editing files.

**What do I mean by this:**

- I want to take files with the extension ('.bpmn')
- Change this extension to ('.xml')
- Conduct some methods on this file using Python native libraries
- Change the file extension back to ('.bpmn') leaving it in it's
  original state

My current code is rather janky in that it collects all the files **in the current directory** as a list,

iterates through the files that contain a '.bpmn' extension and tries to rename it. However using `os.rename()` would first rename the file, then the program would crash resulting in the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxxxxxxx.bpmn'
```

But it would successfully rename the file, but then upon re-running the program it would not crash and do it's job as intended. I've tried to use `shutil.move()` as drop-in replacement for `os.rename()` however this is resulting in the same issues. Perhaps I'm missing some nuance about the entire process?

Code:

```
def main():

    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    for f in files:
        parseAble = False
        temp = ''
        if f.split('.')[1] == 'bpmn':
            print(f.split('.')[1])
            shutil.move(f,f.split('.')[0]+'.xml')
            print(f)
            parseAble = True
        elif f.split('.')[1] == 'xml':
            parseAble = True

        if parseAble == True:
            print(f)
            x = FileParser(f)
            x.getLaneInfo()
            x.getTaskData()
            x.sortTasks()
            x.collectUrls()
            x.outputJsonFile(x.serialize())
            shutil.move(f, f.split('.')[0]+'.bpmn')
```

Comment: first, use `os.rename`. Then why do you need renaming? doesn't the code works with original non-xml extension?

Comment: no, because python's xml library does not recognise the .bpmn extension for whatever reason @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the point is neither `os.rename()` or `shutil.remove()` are functioning properly in this case, I was just testing the latter to see if it made a difference

Comment: I wouldn't do that anyway, can't you _copy_ your files with the proper xml name in a temporary dir, so no need to rename back / cleanup? this looks very fragile to me

Comment: Lots more printouts may help. Changing what you iterate over (by renaming files you change what os.listdir sees) is mostly not well-defined, but I don't see how that would cause the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see with your code is that you are renaming your files with the names on the list but you aren't updating the filename value after renaming, because of that your code is still trying to open the `.bpmn` and fails because the file doesn't exist with that name and works properly the second time because the list is unaltered in that second run. so a simple modification to your code that should work is the following:

```
def main():

    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    for f in files:
        parseAble = False
        temp = ''
        # The -1 ensures that you're getting the actual file extension of 
        # the file, your previous code will fail with filenames like
        # "file.bpmn.xml"
        if f.split('.')[-1] == 'bpmn':
            print(f.split('.')[-1])
            n = '.'.join(f.split('.')[:-1]) + '.xml'
            shutil.move(f, n)
            print(f + ' > ' + n)
            parseAble = True
        elif f.split('.')[-1] == 'xml':
            parseAble = True
            n = f

        if parseAble == True:
            print(n)
            x = FileParser(n)
            x.getLaneInfo()
            x.getTaskData()
            x.sortTasks()
            x.collectUrls()
            x.outputJsonFile(x.serialize())
            shutil.move(n, f)
```